# How to enable Two finger scrolling on Lenovo Thinkpad T400/W540

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

It is disabled (greyed out) in Mouse and Touchpad settings. Edge scrolling works though :) Tried many solutions available online but couldn't succeed.

My touchpad is

SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can be enabled also using commands:

```
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 4
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width" 8
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1 0
```

This was tested on Lenovo T410, T430, and T430s.

Comment: Wow, excellent it works on T400 as well. Thanks :)

Comment: Works great, but changes are not saved for when I restart. How do I do that?

Comment: Just add the line(s) to your .bashrc.

Comment: it does not work for me!! :( I am using lenovo z410 and ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thank you very much. Working perfectly in a Lenovo T-400 :)