# (thinkpad t400) Two-finger scroll stops working after reboot

Tags: multi-touch, synaptics

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and I really want to use two-finger scrolling on the Synaptics TouchPad.

I can't activate it in the System Preferences because the checkbox is disabled. Finally I managed to get it up and running as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/186895). But after rebooting the system it just doesn't work any more.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a workaround. Dont't know if it is the way to go - but at least it works for me:

**Step 1:**
I created a shell script enableMultitouch.sh as root in the directory /usr/local/bin/ and made it executable. (As described here: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Autostart#Autostart-ueber-Skript.)

**Step 2:**
I pasted the commands as mentioned in the post that described how to enable multi-touch:

```
#!/bin/sh
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 4
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width" 8
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1 0
```

As described here: [How to enable Two finger scrolling on Lenovo Thinkpad T400/W540](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186895/how-to-enable-two-finger-scrolling-on-lenovo-thinkpad-t400-in-ubuntu-12-04-64-bi?lq=1)

**Step 3:**
Finally I added the script to the startup applications. And now two-finger-scrolling works just fine.

Hope this is somehow helpful...

Cheers!