# How can i make a command stay active after a restart to the computer?

Tags: autostart

I used a command i saw here to make my touch pad in lenovo 330 to scroll with 2 fingers and it worked exactly as i wanted but after each reset to the computer I need to retype the commend. Can you please tell me how i can make this command stay after i close my computer?

Comment: Are you talking about [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/186952/88802)? You tried to comment on it using an answer, which I flagged for removal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start applications at startup automatically?](http://askubuntu.com/q/48321/65926)

Comment: @EricCarvalho Almost. He'll need to make a script file to run several commands.

Comment: @gertvdijk That's OK, but I still think this question should be rephrased or maybe the answer you pointed should be improved to include persistence between reboots.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the command. If X doesn't need to be running to do it, and it can be run as root, just add it to `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: Well, usually they're depending on X, so running in `rc.local` isn't really recommended/reliable. I should recommend starting this in the DE session as a startup script.

Answer (score 0):

Commands can't "stay" after rebooting the computer. When you shut it down and the power gets cut off, or when you reboot and the memory is cleared, things are *gone* from the memory.

You can, though, either keep the system state, by hibernating and resuming, or, what I expect to be the best solution for you, run the command after each boot.

As your command is probably something for X Windows, it must be executed *after* starting X Windows. Here I do that by adding the command to `~/.xinitrc`, but that's for `startx`, I think Ubuntu by default uses a graphical login screen, so you would need to use some other `~/.xsomething` file. Perhaps `~/.xprofile`?