# Ubuntu 14.04 two finger scroll

Tags: 14.04, mouse, lenovo, mouse-scroll

I have a lenovo z510. I recently multibooted it with ubuntu 14.04
I have tried a lot , but i couldn't enable a two finger scroll.
There is no option for it in mouse settings.
i also tried using ubuntu tweak tool, but with no effect.
pls help me out

![output of xinput ] https://i.stack.imgur.com/qndau.jpg

Comment: Can you try the solution proposed here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/186895/how-to-enable-two-finger-scrolling-on-lenovo-thinkpad-t400-in-ubuntu-12-04-64-bi

Comment: @levlaz , i tried it but it says
unable to find device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad 
what to do next??

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add output of "xinput" command to your question

Comment: @Pilot6 I have added the output image for xinput

Comment: You do not need to add pictures, just select text, copy and paste. There is no touchpad at all detected.

Comment: @Pilot6 , so how do I configure it to enable two finger scroll ?

Comment: It looks like this touchpad is not supported.

Comment: So there is no way in which I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to edit your xorg.conf file, which lives in the /etc/X11 directory.  Try adding a line in the config file that says:

```
Option    "VertTwoFingerScroll"  "1"
```

There are lots of customizations you can make to your touchpad config using that xorg.conf document.  Check out all the possibilities at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad